# I get INVALID_PASSWORD after import user account with CLI firebase auth:import with python script

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to set a user account with fixed parameters into Firebase with the CLI, and after success uploading the data, and then test it I get INVALID_PASSWORD in the logs

I think is related with salt and hash, Am I setting these values incorrectly?

There are others Q.A here that are related,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40851390/2513972

but I trying with python, so please help me, I stuck here.

```
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256
from passlib.utils import to_bytes, to_native_str
import base64

PASSWORD = 'aA123456*'
ROUND = 20000
SALT = to_bytes('google')

hash1 = pbkdf2_sha256.using(salt=SALT,rounds=ROUND).hash(PASSWORD)
print(pbkdf2_sha256.identify(hash1)) 
# True 
print(pbkdf2_sha256.verify(PASSWORD,hash1)) 
# True
print(hash1) 
# $pbkdf2-sha256$20000$Z29vZ2xl$PtFLyZHJJucUa2KBg1iJeVJsivis8JimRhFifRRKlFc

print(base64.b64encode(b'Z29vZ2xl')) 
# b'WjI5dloyeGw='
print(base64.b64encode(b'PtFLyZHJJucUa2KBg1iJeVJsivis8JimRhFifRRKlFc')) 
# b'UHRGTHlaSEpKdWNVYTJLQmcxaUplVkpzaXZpczhKaW1SaEZpZlJSS2xGYw==' 

# firebase auth:import sandbox/account_file.csv --hash-algo=PBKDF2_SHA256 --rounds=20000 --project <project_name>

# account_file.csv
# 555000444,example@gmail.com,false,UHRGTHlaSEpKdWNVYTJLQmcxaUplVkpzaXZpczhKaW1SaEZpZlJSS2xGYw==,WjI5dloyeGw=,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Answer (score 0):

The password has already the values in base64 format, so not need to parse with base64.b64encode method again.

```
# account_file.csv
# 555000444,example@gmail.com,false,PtFLyZHJJucUa2KBg1iJeVJsivis8JimRhFifRRKlFc,Z29vZ2xl,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```